# A system of two nonlinear algebraic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to determine real solutions $x,y$ for the following system of nonlinear equations in terms of the real constants $a,b,k$?

$$
a=kx(1-y^2)\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad b=ky(1-x^2).
$$
If so, what is (are) the solution(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out a graphical solution here: [link](https://ggbm.at/BNR6DZsb)

[image]

The system has been transformed to
$$
A = x(1-y^2) \quad \quad B = y (1-x^2)
$$
where $A = a/k$ and $B= b/k$.

Answer (score 0):

Square the first equation $a^2 = k^2x^2(1-y^2)^2$. Now $k^2(1-y^2)^2$ minus this equation gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
k^2(1-y^2)^2-a^2 = k^2(1-y^2)^2(1-x^2)
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply this by $y$ and substitute for $ky(1-x^2)=b$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{red}{y(k^2(1-y^2)^2-a^2) = kb(1-y^2)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is a quintic (order $5$) in $y$ and will not be easy to solve.